# unread flag is not being updated with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a `conversations` collection in my database, and I'm using Mongoose to update the `unread` flag of a single document.

This is my code:

```
router.post('/reply/:conversation_id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
  Conversation.findById(req.params.conversation_id, (err, conversation) => {

    // If the user that's logged in was the one who created the conversation, and is submitting a reply, run this code
    if (req.user._id == conversation.created_by_user_id) {
      User.findById(conversation.sent_to_user_id, (err, user) => {
        Message.create({
          //...
        }, (err, message) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            message.conversations.push(conversation._id)
            conversation.unread = true
            conversation.save()  // This is being saved to the database
            message.save()
            res.redirect('/conversations/' + conversation._id)
          }
        })
      })
    } else {
    // Otherwise, if the user that's logged in was *not* the one who created the conversation, and is submitting a reply, run this code

      User.findById(conversation.created_by_user_id, (err, user) => {
        Message.create({
          //...
        }, (err, message) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            message.conversations.push(conversation._id)
            conversation.unread = true
            conversation.save() // This is not being saved
            message.save()
            res.redirect('/conversations/' + conversation._id)
          }
        })
      })
    }
  })
});
```

The `if` part saves `conversation.unread = true` to the db.  The `else` part does not.

Both parts of the conditional essentially do the same thing (save the conversation's `unread` flag as `true`, and save the message), but only the first part of the conditional works when setting `unread` to true.

Can someone please help me figure out why the `unread` flag is not being saved as `true` in the `else` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call `save` synchronously.

`.save` takes a callback. It is asynchronous.

See my version below.

```
router.post('/reply/:conversation_id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
  Conversation.findById(req.params.conversation_id, (err, conversation) => {

    // If the user that's logged in was the one who created the conversation, and is submitting a reply, run this code
    if (req.user._id == conversation.created_by_user_id) {
      User.findById(conversation.sent_to_user_id, (err, user) => {
        Message.create({
          //...
        }, (err, message) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            message.conversations.push(conversation._id)
            conversation.unread = true
            conversation.save()  // This is being saved to the database
            message.save()
            res.redirect('/conversations/' + conversation._id)
          }
        })
      })
    } else {
    // Otherwise, if the user that's logged in was *not* the one who created the conversation, and is submitting a reply, run this code

    User.findById(conversation.created_by_user_id, (err, user) => {
      Message.create({
          //...
        }, (err, message) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)

            //return here
            return res.redirect('/error'); //

          } else {
            message.conversations.push(conversation._id)
            conversation.unread = true

            //.save takes a function callback
            conversation.save((err) => {

              //.save takes a function callback
              message.save((err) => {
                res.redirect('/conversations/' + conversation._id)
              })
            })
          }
        })
    })
  }
})
});
```